# Como fazer uma página para saber o IPv6?

Tags: php, ip, ipv6

Para saber o IPv4 poderei utilizar o código numa página:

```
<?php
    echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
?>
```

Mas não consigo encontrar nada parecido para fazer o mesmo com IPv6, o que me aparece muito é já sites com conversores.

Mesmo que não exista um código como o acima para IPv6, gostava de poder fazer um que fixe-se a conversão automaticamente para IPv6.

E o resultado final fosse por exemplo `2002:55F6:9A82:0:0:0:0:0` como se pode ver no [link](http://ip-lookup.net/?2002:55F6:9A82:0:0:0:0:0)

Comment: O que pretendo fazer é o que aparece nestes links O meu ipv4 (http://ip-lookup.net/?85.246.154.130) e O meu ipv6 (http://ip-lookup.net/?2002:55F6:9A82:0:0:0:0:0)

Answer (score 8):

### O que define o endereço é a conexão

A variável `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];` mostra tanto IPv4 quanto IPv6. Só depende de como está configurada a rede do servidor, e do modo que o cliente acessou sua página.

Se a máquina está servindo um endereço via IPv4 você vai ter algo como:

```
208.67.222.222
```

se estiver servindo por IPv6, já terá algo nessa linha:

```
2001:0db8:85a3:08d3:1319:8a2e:0370:7344
```

> Edit em resposta a um comment: se você já tem um servidor que atende IPv6, basta forçar a requisição IPv6 para o seu servidor para ver o `REMOTE_ADDR` funcionando na prática. Por exemplo, pondo o IPv6 no `href` de algum link, ou no URL de um `iframe` ou requisição *ajax* se preferir. Nada impede de você testar tanto IPv4 quanto IPv6 na mesma página, mas para isso precisa fazer as duas requisições separadamente.

### Para padronizar o **armazenamento**

O PHP tem a função [`inet_pton()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.inet-pton.php), que entende as duas formas, e converte o endereço para uma versão compacta binária.

Só pra exemplificar, fiz uma pequena função que converte qualquer IP válido em IPv6 longo:

```
<?php
   function normalizeIP( $ip ) {
      $ip = inet_pton( $ip );
      if( strlen( $ip ) < 5 ) {
         $ip = chr( 255 ).chr( 255 ).str_pad( $ip, 4, chr( 0 ), STR_PAD_LEFT );
      }
      $ip = str_split( str_pad( $ip, 16, chr( 0 ), STR_PAD_LEFT ) );
      $out = '';
      for( $i = 0; $i < 16; ) {
         if( $i && $i % 2 == 0 ) $out .= ':';
         $out .= str_pad( dechex( ord( $ip[$i++] ) ), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
      }
      return $out;
   }
?>
```

Veja no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/WbF48U)**.

Claro que na prática provavelmente você não vair precisar de nada disso, basta armazenar o resultado do `inet_pton()` num campo que aceite strings binárias, de tamanho variável até 16 caracteres.

### Em resumo

Isto depende apenas da configuração da conexão do servidor, e inclusive se a máquina atender pelos dois protocolos, pode acontecer de o cliente `A` estar usando IPv4, e um cliente `B` por IPv6. Ambos terão o IP respectivo sendo armazenado em `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`.

**Caso você tenha os dois protocolos ativados no servidor**, pode ser que o IPv4 seja convertido numa notação de IPv6 e você tenha estes resultados (notar o prefixo `::ffff` indicando que se trata de um IPv4 em formato de IPv6):

```
::ffff:192.000.002.124
::ffff:192.0.2.124
0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:c000:027c
::ffff:c000:027c
::ffff:c000:27c
```

Todos os endereços acima equivalem ao IPv4 `192.0.2.124`.

Comment: Não consegui que funciona-se com este teu código entretanto coloquei como comentário da pergunta um site com o resultado pretendido, obrigado @Bacco

Comment: O código funciona perfeitamente, só que você precisa fazer a requisição DNS IPv6 na sua página, senão nao vai. Basta colocar o IPv6 do servidor no href do link, que o $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; vem certinho.

Comment: Ok @Bacco preciso que me explique com um exemplo que eu não estou a conseguir compreender e não estou a conseguir por na pratica.

Comment: faça uma pagina com 2 iframes, num deles vc poe `<iframe src="ipv4.do.server/teste1.php">` no outro `<iframe src="ipv6.do.server/teste1.php">` com a mesma pagina. Cada um vai mostrar um IP diferente do cliente. Se ele nao tiver algum dos dois, um dos frames vai dar erro. se ele tiver os 2, vai aparecer diferente nos frames. TALVEZ vc tenha que criar um apontamento no seu DNS, por exemplo ipv6.example.com só com AAAA, e ipv4.example.com só com A, assim os endereços só atenderão no respectivo IP. Se sua hospedagem atender por IP (vc tiver ip próprio) aí pode usar o numero do ip mesmo.

Comment: Bem @Bacco nem com a sua explicação pratica eu cheguei lá é como se costuma dizer burro velho não aprende línguas, se não se importar muito eu abri uma conta ftp no servidor que eu gostava de lhe passar mas no seu perfil não tem email como posso fazer?

Comment: Não tenho como preparar uma demonstração por não ter nem IPv6 aqui para testar, vou ficar devendo essa. Se sobrar um tempinho mais tarde, vejo se consigo editar a resposta com uma demonstração. Não prometo, mas vou tentar fazer isso qq hora dessas.

Comment: Ok obrigado na mesma.

Comment: @RjpServidor vc tem IP próprio na sua hospedagem? Digo, consegue por uma página sua e acessar só pelo IP? algo acessivel por http://89.xx.xx.xx/teste.php ?

Comment: Sim consigo não tem problema

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17529/discussion-between-bacco-and-rjp-servidor).